# How do you send sms with android sdk

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am trying to figure out how to send sms from my application. I have tried the following:

```
try { 
    String newNumber, newMessage;
    newNumber = number.getText().toString();
    newMessage = message.getText().toString();
    smsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(newNumber, null, newMessage,null, null);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
     }  
    }
}
    };thread.start();
```

But I get a log cat with this:

> 07-23 09:03:42.378: I/Process(14426): Sending signal. PID: 14426 SIG:
>   9 07-23 09:06:18.972: W/dalvikvm(14529): threadid=11: thread exiting
>   with uncaught exception (group=0x40a381f8) 07-23 09:06:18.972:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14529): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-885 07-23
>   09:06:18.972: E/AndroidRuntime(14529): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-23 09:06:18.972: E/AndroidRuntime(14529):  at
>   com.johnnydicamillo.sms.SmsSpammerActivity$1.run(SmsSpammerActivity.java:48)
>   07-23 09:06:19.238: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14529): showStatusIcon
>   on inactive InputConnection 07-23 09:06:44.855: I/Process(14529):
>   Sending signal. PID: 14529 SIG: 9

Comment: First format your code. Second, accept more answers. And third, what line is the one throwing the NPE.

Comment: smsManager.sendTextMessage(newNumber, null, newMessage,
                                    null, null); and I did format but this is what my mac did.

Comment: Why are letting your main thread sleep???

Comment: sorry guys just updated the code to what it, I am new and was Just trying to figure it out on my own. I have tried researching and using the code there but I guess I am doing something wrong or missed something.

Comment: @SergeyK. I've seen this used for GTalkSMS, which allows one to control the phone via XMPP. Including sending SMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `smsManager` may be null, `getDefault()` is a static method used to get the default instance of an `SmsManager` and it doesn't show that you are setting anything. You probably want that line to be something like:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
```